# Forcing macro expansion

Tags: macros, expansion

I have done my best to understand `\expandafter`, `\edef` and friends, but I can't find a way of using them to force expansion of the parameter passed in to the macro `\FormatDate` in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@FormatDateAuxA#1/#2/#3 #4.{%
    % Day
            \number#3\relax\space
    % Month
            \ifcase#2{}?#2?\or
            January\or February\or March\or April\or
            May\or June\or July\or August\or
            September\or October\or November\or December\else
            ?#2?\fi\space
    % Year
            \ifnum#1>99{}#1\else\ifnum#1>9{}19#1\else190#1\fi\fi}
\def\@FormatDateAuxB#1$#2.{{
    \typeout{\noexpand#1}
    \@FormatDateAuxA#1 X.}}
\def\FormatDate#1{\@FormatDateAuxB#1$X.}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\FormatDate{2015/4/15}
\def\Date{2015/4/15}
\FormatDate{\Date}
\end{document}
```

The above gives the following output.

```
2015/4/15
\Date 
! Argument of \@FormatDateAuxA has an extra }.
```

\Date hasn't been expanded and that has (presumably) stopped the pattern-matching for the parameter of `\@FormatDateAuxA` working. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\@FormatDateAuxA#1/#2/#3 #4.{%
    % Day
            \number#3\relax\space
    % Month
            \ifcase#2{}?#2?\or
            January\or February\or March\or April\or
            May\or June\or July\or August\or
            September\or October\or November\or December\else
            ?#2?\fi\space
    % Year
            \ifnum#1>99{}#1\else\ifnum#1>9{}19#1\else190#1\fi\fi}
\def\@FormatDateAuxB#1$#2.{{
    \typeout{\noexpand#1}
    \@FormatDateAuxA#1 X.}}
\def\FormatDate#1{\expandafter\@FormatDateAuxB#1$X.}
                  %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\FormatDate{2015/4/15}
\def\Date{2015/4/15}
\FormatDate{\Date}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. That certainly works. Unfortunately, it means that I will have to change several style files. Is it not possible to solve this without changing \FormatDate?

Comment: @RobArthan perhaps I misunderstood, I thought you _wanted_ to change that. You could do  `\expandafter\FormatDate\expandafter{\Date}` without changing the macro, but then your document source looks uglier:-)

Comment: I probably do want to change the style files eventually, but I also wanted to know if there was a quick local fix. Thanks for providing that