# Undefined control sequence when using \edef with \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, tikz-matrix

I’m attempting to define a command to build several similar tikz nodes. These nodes differ only by one parameter (`#2` below). Here are the main questions I’ve referenced so far:

- [Foreach inside a TikZ matrix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22275/foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix)
- [Forcing macro expansion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238716/forcing-macro-expansion)
- [Appending to Variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38200/appending-to-variables)
- [How to left-pad an integer with zeroes to make it many digits?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412224/how-to-left-pad-an-integer-with-zeroes-to-make-it-many-digits) for (`\num[...]`)

I feel like I’m so close, but I have no idea where to go beyond what I’ve detailed below. The left part of this diagram is pretty much the expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Here’s the current command definition:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{ht_num} = [draw, semithick]
\tikzstyle{ht_hash} = [draw, semithick, minimum width=2em]

\NewDocumentCommand \HashTable { m m } {%
    \def\MatrixContent{\empty}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nn{2^#2-1}
    \foreach \n in {0,...,\nn}{%
        \edef\MatrixContent{\unexpanded\expandafter{\MatrixContent}\unexpanded\expandafter{%
            \node[ht_hash] (#1-\n) {\num[minimum-integer-digits=#2]{\pgfmathbin{\n}\pgfmathresult}}; \\
        }}
    }

    \matrix [outer sep=0pt,every node/.style={anchor=west}] (#1) {
        \node[ht_num] (#1-a) {#2}; \\
        \MatrixContent
    };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \HashTable{table1}{2}
    % Other tikz nodes...
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And finally, the error message:

```
./Diagrams.tex:398: Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.398 ^^I^^I\end{tikzpicture}
                             \end{center}
```

Which isn’t very helpful.

---

I tried removing the code from a command and placing it directly in the document with hardcoded values:

```
\def\MatrixContent{\empty}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nn{2^2-1}
\foreach \n in {0,...,\nn}{%
    \edef\MatrixContent{\unexpanded\expandafter{\MatrixContent}\unexpanded\expandafter{%
        \node[ht_hash] (table-\n) {\n};
    }}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix [outer sep=0pt,every node/.style={anchor=west}] (table) {
        \MatrixContent
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produced a new error:

```
./Diagrams.tex:403: Undefined control sequence.
\pgffor@body ... }\unexpanded \expandafter {\node 
                                                  [ht_hash] (table-\n ) {...
l.403 ^^I^^I}
```

---

And finally, I tried using a different method for building `\MatrixContent`:

```
\let\MatrixContent\empty
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\nn{2^2-1}
\foreach \n in {0,...,\nn}{%
    \expandafter\gappto\expandafter\MatrixContent\expandafter{%
        \node[ht_hash] (table-\n) {\n};
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture} ...
```

Producing yet another error:

```
./Diagrams.tex:413: Undefined control sequence.
\pgffor@body ...MatrixContent \expandafter {\node 
                                                  [ht_hash] (table-\n ) {...
l.413 ^^I^^I}
```

Comment: Welcome! You are just posting fragments. Even though one can infer the required packages from the commands you use, it is not clear what the styles `ht_num` and `ht_hash` do. Please provide us with a *complete* yet minimal document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: BTW, your first example works if you add `\\ ` after `\MatrixContent`, i.e. `\matrix [outer sep=0pt,every node/.style={anchor=west}] (#1) {
        \node[ht_num] (#1-a) {#2}; \\
        \MatrixContent \\
    };`. (It is true, though, that the error message does not immediately tell you that.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for the tip, I’ve updated the first example to be a mcve. I’m thoroughly confused why adding that additional `\\ ` allows the document to compile okay, but it doesn’t appear to output anything in place of `\MatrixContent`

Comment: This is because you use `\edef` and `\foreach` starts a group, so the definitions are local and get forgotten. (Replacing `\edef` by `\xdef` yields an error, though, and I need still to figure out what you wish to do.) BTW, which package does `\num[minimum-integer-digits=#2]` come from?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat It’s from `siunitx`, updated to include in mcve & link to source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to speculate what you want to do, so my guess it is something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\tikzset{ht_num/.style={draw, semithick},
ht_hash/.style={draw, semithick, minimum width=2em}}
\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand \HashTable { m m } {%
    \def\MatrixContent{\empty}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nn{2^#2-1}
    \foreach \n in {0,...,\nn}{%
        \pgfmathbin{\n}%
        \edef\myresult{|[ht_hash]| 
        \num[minimum-integer-digits=#2]{\pgfmathresult}}%
        \xappto\MatrixContent{\expandonce{\myresult\\}}%
    }
    \matrix [outer sep=0pt,matrix of nodes] (#1) {
        |[ht_num,name=#1-a]|  #2 \\
        \MatrixContent %\\
    };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \HashTable{table1}{2}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comments:

1. You were loading but not using the `matrix` library. I think using it makes things much simpler here.
2. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.
3. I basically used the commented out solution in [Martin Scharrer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22275/foreach-inside-a-tikz-matrix).
4. A Ti*k*Z matrix has counts `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow` and `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` which, when used, may allow you to make this whole enterprise much simpler. Yet I am not sure I am on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for this! I thought I’d tried everything from my linked questions, but I guess not.

Comment: @MTCoster Probably there is. In any case, from the Ti*k*Z point of view the correct syntax is `ht_hash/.style={draw, semithick, minimum width=2em,font=\ttfamily}`, i.e. add the font information to the definition of the style. Probably this will not have an effect because you use `siunitx`. So you probably need to look up in its manual how you change the font in `\num`, or ask a new question. I personally do not use `siunitx`.

Comment: I tried that after posting my comment, and it did work through `\num`. Thanks again

Comment: BTW, if you want to left-align the cells, you only need to add `cells={nodes={anchor=west}}` to the matrix option. In general a `matrix of nodes` is easier to deal with because you can steer more things with keys.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems in your code.

1. `\foreach` executes each cycle in a group, so any definition made inside it is forgotten as soon as the group ends, unless it is done *globally*; thus not `\edef`, but `\xdef` (global expanded definition)
2. The code `\unexpanded\expandafter{\MatrixContent}` is meant to access the *previous* value of `\MatrixContents` (but with no further expansion). You don't want to expand `\node...`, so that should be the argument of a simple `\unexpanded`; however it is the only token that should be protected from expansion, together with `\\`, so a couple of `\noexpand` suffice; `\num` is by itself protected from expanding in `\edef` or `\xdef`.
3. Further problem: `\num` wants to see a number, not the set of instruction to produce it, so `\pgfmathbin{\n}` should be done before updating `\MatrixContent`; and `\pgfmathresult` should not be hidden in `\unexpanded`.
4. `\tikzstyle` has been deprecated for a few years.

Here's the amended code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  ht_num/.style={draw, semithick},
  ht_hash/.style={draw, semithick, minimum width=2em},
}

\newcommand\HashTable[2]{%
  \def\MatrixContent{}% not \empty
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nn{2^(#2)-1}
  \foreach \n in {0,...,\nn}{%
    \pgfmathbin{\n}% the current value in binary format
    \xdef\MatrixContent{%
      \unexpanded\expandafter{\MatrixContent}% the previous value
      \noexpand\node[ht_hash] (#1-\n) {\num[minimum-integer-digits=#2]{\pgfmathresult}};
      \noexpand\\%
    }%
  }%
  \matrix [outer sep=0pt,every node/.style={anchor=west}] (#1) {
        \node[ht_num] (#1-a) {#2}; \\
        \MatrixContent
  };
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \HashTable{table1}{2}
    % Other tikz nodes...
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \HashTable{table1}{3}
    % Other tikz nodes...
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]